# installing pexpect for python3

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

Installed pexpect for python 2 and this works fine.
Need to use python 3. Machine is Ubuntu 14.04.
Tried install for python 3 but fails; I must be missing something simple? thx.

$sudo pip3 install pexpect
Downloading/unpacking pexpect
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pexpect
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pexpect
Storing debug log for failure in /home/xxxxxx/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Can you see the package when calling `pip3 search pexpect`?

Comment: pip search is ok:

Comment: pip3 search seems to have a network/proxy error.